# Disable backspace in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating an application which takes website address as input from user in Edittext. And I am setting `http://` in Edittext in XML file.

But the problem is that I want to disable backspacing in Edittext when only `http://` present in it. I tried this but it's not working,

```
etLink.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.equals("http://")){
                etLink.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
 });
```

**EDIT**

I can fix this by using `TextView` or `ImageView`, but is there any possibility to done this with `addTextChangedListener` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround can be just placing an `ImageView` with `http://` on `EditText` and give padding to `EditText` so that text starts from right of `ImageView`. And you can append `http://` in java as required.

But for `TextWathcer` approach you can do this -

```
etLink.setText("http://");
String after="";
etLink.setSelection(7);
etLink.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            after=s.toString();
            if(after.length()<7) {

                etLink.setText("http://");
                etLink.setSelection(7);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, instead of `ImageView` I can also use `TextView`. But is there any possibilites with `addTextChangedListener` ?

Comment: But you dont need to use  String -> variable of "After"  .. You can use "charSequence.toString().length()<8)" as if condition inside onTextChanged

Comment: doesn't the Android documentation warn against modifying text in onTextChanged?